# Convert basic html file to a Image

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a php or javascript method of converting a simple html file with text to a JPEG image   and saving it automatically. I would like to be able to pull it into Outlook 2007 as "embedded content" for a company's dynamic disclaimer

Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE

i have found the following script that produces a image with only a string:

```
<?php
$text = "This is a example";
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(700, 300)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 12, 5, 5,  $text, $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Is there a way to get `<br>` tags to work in a php string?

Comment: do you mean an automated version of `Print Screen`?

Comment: print scr on a windows machine. dose not sound like something you need to do more than once.

Comment: If you were under a stable system - say Linux - I'd say you could easily automate this with the command-line utility **`scrot`**.

Comment: basialy it converts normal html text to a image file php script

Comment: still does not sound like something needs automation or to be a graphic over plain text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I have multiline text with GD and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951452/can-i-have-multiline-text-with-gd-and-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `imageTTFtext()` function and concatenation the `<br />` tag.

```
<?php
header(“Content-type: image/gif”);

 $string = 'This is another text i want to include';
 $im = imagecreate( 400, 200 );
 $red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,0,0);
 $blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,255 );
 $font = “/usr/local/jdk121_pre-v1/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaSansRegular.ttf”;

 imageTTFtext( $im, 50, 0, 20, 100, $blue, $font, “This is some text!” );

 imagegif($im);
 ?>
```

I created a canvas with a width of 400 pixels, you'll need a FreeType font in addition to your GD library. with the `imageTTFtext()` function i defined a width of `50` and angle of `0` of the text. so to make the string more complex, you can place the `<br />` tag like this:

```
imageTTFtext( $im, 50, 0, 20, 100, $blue, $font, “This is some text!<br/>”.$string."some other text" );
```

Hope you get the picture now...